Why does the double-angle tangent formula give a different answer for $\tan180^\circ$?
We have, by the double angle formula, $\tan 180^\circ=\frac{2\tan 90^\circ}{1-\tan^290^\circ}$, which means $0=\frac{2(\infty)}{1-(\infty)^2}.$
Isn't that an indeterminate form, because the numerator and denominator are undefined?

$\tan(90) \neq \infty$ . $\tan$ is undefined at that point. It is ambiguous to what $\infty$ even would mean here anyhow.

Consider what happens as $\theta \to 90^\circ$ so that $m = \tan\theta \to \pm \infty$. Even though both expressions $2m$ and $1 - m^2$ are increasing without bound, the denominator is outpacing the numerator in
$$
\tan2\theta = \frac{2m}{1-m^2}.
$$
For example, consider $m = 10^9$. Then,
$$
\frac{2m}{1-m^2} \approx \frac{2 \cdot 10^9}{10^{18}} = 2 \cdot 10^{-9}, 
$$
and the disparity between the numerator and denominator only grows as $m$ grows in magnitude. Clearly, in the limit, this ratio vanishes.

Edited to add more, inspired by the comment below by @Blue:
It makes sense to fill in these holes at every integer multiple of $90^\circ$ since the values of the function $\tan2\theta$ approach zero there anyway. Here's a graph of a couple periods of the function, and you can see that there are these undefined (missing) points on the $\theta$-axis wherever $\theta = (90n)^\circ$ for integer $n$.

There's also a nice algebraic argument for why those values should be filled in as $0$. Multiply the numerator and denominator of the double angle identity by $\cos^2\theta$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tan 2\theta &= \frac{2\tan\theta}{1 - \tan^2 \theta} \\
&= \frac{2\tan\theta \cdot \cos^2 \theta}{\bigl(1 - \tan^2 \theta\bigr) \cdot \cos^2 \theta} \\
&= \frac{2\sin\theta \cos\theta}{\cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta}
\end{aligned}
$$
At any integer multiple of $90^\circ$, we have either $\sin\theta = \pm 1$ and $\cos\theta = 0$ or vice versa. Either way, the expression evaluates to
$$
\frac{2 \cdot (\pm 1) \cdot 0}{\pm 1} = 0,
$$
as expected.
Why does this turn out differently? It stems from the identity
$$
\tan\theta \cdot \cos\theta = \sin\theta, 
$$
which is just a rearrangement of the usual definition of the tangent function. The two expressions evaluate to the same number everywhere that they're both defined. For the sine function on the right, that's at any real number, but for the expression on the left there are holes in the domain.

+1. Although $\dfrac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$ is formally undefined when $\theta=90^\circ$, the existence of the limit indicates that the problem amounts to what we call a "removable discontinuity" of the function (corresponding to a simple "hole" the graph). Very often (and especially with trig identities), we allow limits to fill in holes like this. Teachers (myself included) could/should be clearer about how/when/why we make such allowances.

I edited my answer to include a bit more based on your comment, @Blue. Thanks for the suggestion.

"I edited my answer to include a bit more" ... Nicely done!
